# Picasso and thumbnails. Best practice

Tags: android, thumbnails, picasso

Picasso and thumbnails

Currently I am working of support of old project created by other developers.
I have task to improve images processing.
I can see there, that app creates resized small copy for every image downloaded from server for thumbnails using.
Then images loaded to ImageView with using of BitmapFactory.decodeFile in recycler view.

I know about Picasso and that this is the good practice to use it.
I believe that using of Picasso for creation of thumbnails images for list from original image is better
than creation of separate resized thumbnail for every image.

Is i am correct or maybe wrong ?

Comment: this is opinion-based. You have to take decision on your own.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't have to reinvent the wheel.**

If you have to deal with multiples images (for example: a list of images), resize, etc, I think that **Picasso is a good option**. This library has the best practice in resize, crop, memory leak related with Image.

Of course, is on your own, but you have to use it when it's possible

**Nice coding!**